# Is it possible to prosecute Booking.com if a scam was done by another party through their portal?

Tags: criminal-law, fraud, internet-scam

Due to an in app message request to verify my credit card on Bookingcom I lost a lot of money. I reported it to my bank, Booking.com and the property whose account was compromised.The transaction was tracked to a gaming site and they said they suspended the user's account but they won't return my money. No one is taking accountability for it. I believe it was booking.com's responsibility to protect the user account from hacking. Would it be possible to prosecute them?

Comment: Have your bank issue a chargeback... else I would assume the terms of Booking.com shields them from any liabilty

Comment: I imagine companies have some duty to protect user data, but it's impossible to prevent all avenues of hacking. Booking.com could of course not prevent a user from divulging their information in a phishing scam, or from writing down their username and password and leaving it at a bus stop. If Booking.com did not adequately protect their own database, though, it might be a different story.

Comment: Consider your email address public. Anybody can create a fake email saying they are booking.com or any website. Nobody will take responsibility if you fall for a scam.

Comment: It sounds like you responded to a phishing method pretending to be from Booking.com. If so, then the actual Booking.com was not involved in any way; there's nothing they could have done to prevent it.

Comment: @Sneftel - The phishing link was sent through the in-app messaging module within Booking.com's official app. This is why I was trying to understand the nature of their accountability for this incident.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe it was booking.com's responsibility to protect the user
> account from hacking. Would it be possible to prosecute them?

You are probably wrong.

Section 230 of the Communications Decency Act generally immunizes people who provide services via the Internet from liability for the actions of their users except in cases of sexual exploitation.

Comment: Not sure if the Section 230 of Communications Decency Act would be applicable here, given that Booking.com's HQ is in Netherlands and I am not from the UK either.